# Fixed width of th/td element in PrimeNg table is not respected in Chrome (but does in Firefox)

Tags: html, css, primeng

I am using the PrimeNG table (v15.4.1) and I set the styles to a "frozen" column, i.e. both the `th` and the `td` to the following:

```css
    max-width: 40px !important;
    min-width: 40px !important;
    width: 40px !important;
    padding: 0px;
```

In addition, `box-sizing` of the parent `tr` is `border-box`, if that matters. *There is nothing inside these `th`/`td` elements to push their width*. In Chrome (118.0.5993.70) the actual width is sometimes 40px as requested, but sometimes it's 48px or anything in between. In Firefox it never changes.

So the question is, what could it be about a `th`/`td` element (or its ancestor elements) that would cause the browser not to respect the styles above?

**UPDATE:**

The PrimeNg table is initialized with the following relevant options:

```html
    [reorderableColumns]="true"
    [resizableColumns]="true"
    columnResizeMode="expand"
    [scrollable]="true"
    scrollHeight="flex"
```

These seem to force the table to have a fixed `width` and `min-width` CSS property set to the same size in pixels, e.g. `1000px`. In addition, to support resizing the columns, each column in turn has its own fixed `width` and `max-width` styles. The problem starts when you start hiding/showing columns dynamically, and then the sum of widths of all columns does not match the total width of the table. And since the table width is also persisted and restored from local storage, they can become out of sync, and then the column widths are not respected. I see that there are some related open issues in the PrimeNg repo:

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/11086

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13875

**Bottom line:**
This can happen when the table has a fixed `width` and `min-width` value is pixels, and each `th`/`td` in turn have their own `width` and `max-width` values in pixels, the sum of which does not add up. In that case of course the browser doesn't know what to do, so each browser may choose a different solution.

Comment: Did you try increasing the specificity viz. `table tr th.frozen-column`?

Comment: In the Chrome dev tools, the styles above overwrite all others. They are directly on the element, not in a class. When I inspect the computed width style I cannot see how it's calculated, i.e. where the weird values are coming from, so it's not from another class.

Comment: I think I found it. The `table` element had a fixed `width` and `min-width` (same value in px) applied to it. I think this forces the column widths to be calculated to fit in this width. When I set the class `table.p-datatable-table { width: auto !important; min-width: unset !important; }` the issue seems to be fixed.

Comment: But if I do this, I cannot resize the columns anymore... ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

So, today the solution (a hack, actually) dawned on me. As stated in my question and comments above, the problem starts with what the PrimeNg Table does when you set `[resizableColumns]="true"`. It sets a fixed width on the table (in CSS) and a fixed width on each column (`<th>`'s and `<td>`'s), which may not always add up to the total when you start dynamically adding and removing columns, so the browser doesn't know what to do because the situation is ambiguous.

So what I did is I set `[resizableColumns]="hasResizableColumns"` which is a boolean that starts as `false` when the table is initialized and becomes `true` 1sec after the data has been loaded. I do the same every time a column is dynamically added or removed to the `columns` table input, I set that boolean to `false` and 1sec later I set it to `true` again. This gives the PrimeNg table enough time to do its internal width calculations with no restrictions on the table width (the column widths don't need to add up) and allows the users to resize the columns 1sec later.

And it works (tested on PrimeNg 16.x, but I would bet it works on 15.x as well).